# Syncing Model with bare RxSwift and BehaviourSubject

Tags: swift, synchronization, reactive-programming, rx-swift

i'm new to the world of swift and rxSwfit, and i'm asking for suggestions or criticism with this current solution for example, for syncing blog posts, categories, authors or whatever we need.

Take this classic situation: an observable which gives to every subscriber the last updated data present in the model, and since that moment on, for every synchronization of the model, it emits the new whole pack of data, so the subscribers get and operate on the updated data.

I built an observable who's next value is the combination of his current value (the data present in ram) with the value grabbed from the rest.

Take for the example, the posts:

```
let articoli2       = BehaviorSubject<[Articolo]>(value: [Articolo]()) // ram data, initially empty
var articoli_rest   = PublishSubject<[Articolo]>()  // net data
var idx_articoli2   = [Int:Articolo]()   // used for filtering duplicates
```

Then i create the subscription which updates "articoli2"

```
Observable.zip(articoli2, articoli_rest) { (ram_articoli, rest_articoli) -> [Articolo] in
            var new_articoli = ram_articoli

//Code that merges the data currently present (ram_articoli) 
//with the data grabbed from the net (rest_articoli)
...     
            return new_articoli
            }.subscribe(onNext: { (articoli) in
                self.articoli2.onNext(articoli)

            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Finally, when i want to update the model, i use:

```
func sync_articoli()
{
        get_rest_array(Articolo.self,"https://rest_route").retry(4)
            .subscribe(onNext: { (articoli) in
                    self.articoli_rest.onNext(articoli)
}
```

This function subscribes to the single observable returned by get_rest_array
an when the data from the net is ready, it emits an item on articoli_rest
which in turn updates my articoli2.
The whole thing works but i'm not sure it's really usable and I'm not confident in my solution. Any words? ( blame as much you want )

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.zip()` is an incorrect operator to use for pagination. There is a [scan operator](http://rxmarbles.com/#scan) designed for that cause.

Comment: Thx, I'll rewrite the implementation then. Any words on the overall solution?

Comment: @Fruff I believe it's always better to develop an object oriented solution even if just something that is `Paginable`. Take a look at this blog http://www.yegor256.com/best.html, I bet you will find it fascinating.